# Fatal error - syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, ioncube

The following errors were reported during processing ionCube encoding process:

> function.php:386:Fatal error - syntax error, unexpected end of file

I have tried to check it but I can't get over it. So please Advise.

```
Full code [here][1]
```

https://pastebin.com/bEfkpPas

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is no syntax error in the code you've provided. Most likely it stems from the included PHP since the line numbers are off.